# Are the Croatian word "radije" (rather) and English word "rather" related?

Tags: english, etymology, bosnian-croatian-serbian

The Croatian word "radije" means "rather". Is it related to English "rather"? On one hand, it seems that they can't be, as the Croatian 'd' (in "radije") corresponds to English 't', rather than 'th': "**d**va"-"**t**wo", "**d**eset"-"**t**en", "**d**rvo"-"**t**ree", "**d**viga"-"**t**wig", "**d**omaći"-"**t**ame", "sje**d**iti"-"si**t**"... On the other hand, the similarity between "rather" and "radije" in both form and meaning is huge. What do you think?

Comment: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/radъ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. "Rather" goes back to Old English *hraþe* "quick, soon, early" plus the comparative *-er*. I don't speak Croatian but it looks like your word comes from a root for "prefer".

Comment: The root is *rad*, and *-ije* is a comparative ending.  The roots aren’t related, but the structure is similar.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer That would make a good answer!